# passenger can not find custom installation ruby's gems

Tags: ruby, nginx, gitlab, passenger

I installed passenger and nginx as the replacement of gitlab built-in nginx and puma service. In nginx's configuration file gitlab.conf, I had set variable  `passenger_ruby` to `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby`. but when nginx service is up, passenger cannot spawn ruby application correctly. In nginx's error.log, it reports like below

```
App 22480 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2023-02-09 14:38:56.3245 21868/Tw age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not 
spawn process for application /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails: 
The application encountered the following error: 
Could not find graphql-docs-1.6.0, lefthook-0.8.0, rubocop-0.93.1, solargraph-0.44.3, 
letter_opener_web-2.0.0, better_errors-2.9.1, thin-1.8.0, sprite-factory-1.7.1, 
deprecation_toolkit-1.5.1, bullet-6.1.3, pry-byebug-3.9.0, pry-rails-0.3.9, pry-shell-0.5.0, 
awesome_print-1.9.2, database_cleaner-1.7.0, factory_bot_rails-6.2.0, rspec-rails-5.0.1,
```

It's seems like passenger cannot find gems which were relied by gitlab-rails, gems' location can be found by command `gem environment`：

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.5 (2021-11-24 patchlevel 203) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE:
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0   # here
```

which configuration I need to change to fix this problem?

I tried to change passenger's default confiugration file `locations.ini`，which was located by `passenger-config --root`，changed from

```
ruby_libdir=/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
```

to

```
ruby_libdir=/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
```

but it's not work.